# How to add hosting for Gen.xyz websites

Tags: host

i want to change the hosting of samplewebname.xyz registered at gen.xyz website into godaddy host. I added the domain in godaddy but still the website showing weebly.com web profile.when i open the account in gen.xyz in the hosting field it showing "launch weebly free".  there is no way to change the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to add your domain in godaddy host and note down the ip address then go to your gen.xyz account

> Go to **my domain section** and click on **manage**
>
> Then go to **Nameservers** section and open **DNS Management**
>
> Change the **IP Address** to your **Godaddy host IP**

wait for few mins